# Sending unique reminder email to individual recipient from a list

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying send email reminder to individual recipient with their associated userID for them to complete a survey. Each recipient can own multiple userID. The email reminder will only be triggered if the recipient did not complete the survey.

The problem is that the all reminders includes all userID from the other recipients who have yet to send their response. How do I solve this? Thank you.

```
Sub SendReminderMail()
    Dim OutLookApp As Object
    Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim MailDest As String
    Dim DGName As String 

    Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("OutLook.Application")
    Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutLookMailItem
    MailDest=""

    For iCounter =1 to WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(16))
        If MailDest =""And Cells(iCounter,14) = "" Then
            MailDest = Cells(iCounter,16).Value
            DGName = Cells(iCounter,12).Value
        ElseIf  MailDest<>  ""  And  Cells(iCounter,14)="" Then
            MailDest = MailDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter,16)
            DGName = DGName & ";" & Cells(iCounter,12)
        End If
    Next iCounter

    .BCC =  MailDest
    .Subject =
    .HTMLBody = "Message" & "<br/><br/>" & DGName & "<br/><br/>" & "Message"
```

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Welcom Ash, which of your variables holds the userID's? Or is it extracted from a cell value? Gotta catch em all ;)

Comment: Hi @Luuklag , DGName is the variable that holds the userID. Sorry for not making excluding that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short example shows you how to collect the user IDs for each mail address of your example data. You need to send your email where I put the comment.

```
Option Explicit

Sub example()

    Dim DGName As String

    Dim MailDest As String
    MailDest = Cells(2, 16) 'initialize

    Dim iCounter As Long
    For iCounter = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(16)) + 1
        If Cells(iCounter, 14) = vbNullString Then
            If MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 16) Then
                DGName = IIf(DGName <> vbNullString, DGName & ";", vbNullString) & Cells(iCounter, 12)
            ElseIf MailDest <> vbNullString Then
                Debug.Print "SendMail to " & MailDest, DGName
                'send your email here
                DGName = Cells(iCounter, 12)
                MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 16)
            End If
        End If
    Next iCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, thanks again for your help :) . The only issue is that it will not send the reminder when the loop detects a new email. This is what I have enter in the blank. 
`OutLookMailItem.BCC = MailDest

OutLookMailItem.Subject = "Survey Reminder"

OutLookMailItem.HTMLBody = "message" & DGName & "message"

    OutLookMailItem.send`

Comment: @AshKetchum did you put it **exactly** at the position where I put the comment? And you should use `.To` instead of `.BCC` I think you cannot send a mail without at least one `.To` address.

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, yes. After changing to `.To`, it still has the error "The item has been moved or deleted".

Comment: Hi @Pᴇʜ, I managed to solve the issue. I moved `Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)` into the For Loop. It is now breathing. Thank you again @Pᴇʜ for your response

Comment: @AshKetchum well, of course. I should have mentioned that too, but I just concentrated on the actual issue of combining the IDs of one address. If this solved your question please mark it as solution.

Comment: Thanks again :). It has been a pleasure working with you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub SendReminderMail2()
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim iCounter As Integer
Dim MailDest As String
Dim DGName() As String 'each user can have multiple usernames
    Dim DGNamecounter As Long
ReDim usedmaildest(0)
    Dim usedMailcounter As Long
    Dim emailused As Boolean

Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("OutLook.Application")

For iCounter = 2 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(16)) 'from the second column to the end
    If Cells(iCounter, 14) = "Yes" Then 'if it needs feedback
        MailDest = Cells(iCounter, 16)
        For j = LBound(usedmaildest) To UBound(usedmaildest) 'if the email has been sent
            If MailDest = usedmaildest(j) Then emailused = True 'then mark this line as redundant
        Next j
        If Not emailused Then 'and abort further processing, otherwise:
            ReDim Preserve usedmaildest(usedMailcounter) 'increase the used email addresses array if necessary
            usedmaildest(usedMailcounter) = MailDest 'add the current email address to the used ones
            usedMailcounter = usedMailcounter + 1 'increase the counter of the used mail addresses
            'then we need to find all the usernames for this email address

            For k = iCounter To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(16)) 'look from the current row down
                If Cells(k, 14) = "Yes" And Cells(k, 16) = MailDest Then 'if it's the same email and needs feedback
                    ReDim Preserve DGName(DGNamecounter) 'increase the username array if necessary
                    DGName(DGNamecounter) = Cells(k, 12) 'add the current username to the array
                    DGNamecounter = DGNamecounter + 1 'increase the array counter
                End If
            Next k
            'sending the email
            Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutLookMailItem
                .BCC = MailDest
                .Subject = "Account feedback"
                'we insert all the usernames relating to the email address
                .HTMLBody = "This email is concerning username" & IIf(DGNamecounter = 1, "", "s") & "<br/><br/>" & Join(DGName, "<br/>") & "<br/><br/>" & "Message"
                .Display
                '.Send
            End With

            DGNamecounter = 0 ' reducing the array counter to 0

        End If
        emailused = False ' set your boolean back to default
    End If
Next iCounter

End Sub
```

I guess you wanted each address to get one email, containing each username that they need to give feedback for.
This macro does that while introducing you to arrays.